# Python 'AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'amount'

Tags: python, attributes, attributeerror

My apologies if this error seems obvious; I am very new to Python.

I'm trying to write a small part of roulette simulator.
My code currently looks like this:

```
import os
import random
import copy

red = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 12, 14, 16, 18, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 30, 32, 34, 36}
black = {2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 11, 13, 15, 17, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 29, 31, 33, 35}

balance = 512  # we start with 512$


class Bet:
    def __init__(self, color_param, amount_param):
        self.color = color_param
        self.amount = amount_param

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Bet color:%r amount:%r>" % (self.color, self.amount)


class Result:
    def __init__(self, number_param, color_param):
        self.number = number_param
        self.color = color_param

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Result number:%r color:%r>" % (self.number, self.color)


def roll():
    result_number = random.randint(0, 36)
    if result_number in red:
        return Result(result_number, "red")
    elif result_number in black:
        return Result(result_number, "black")
    else:
        return Result(result_number, "green")


def bet(result, former_result, former_bet):
    if result.number in red:
        if (former_result is not None) and (former_bet is not None) and (former_result.number in red):
            current_bet = Bet("black", former_bet.amount * 2)
        else:
            current_bet = Bet("black", 1)
    elif result.number in black:
        if (former_result is not None) and (former_bet is not None) and (former_result.number in black):
            current_bet = Bet("red", former_bet.amount * 2)
        else:
            current_bet = Bet("red", 1)
    else:
        current_bet = None
    return current_bet


def main():
    former_result = None
    former_bet = None

    for x in range(0, 10):
        result = roll()
        current_bet = bet(result, former_result, former_bet)

        print(repr(former_result))
        print(repr(former_bet), "\n")

        former_result = copy.deepcopy(result)
        former_bet = copy.deepcopy(bet)

        print(repr(result))
        print(repr(current_bet), "\n")
```

but when it gets to the line

```
current_bet = Bet("red", former_bet.amount * 2)
```

I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'amount'
```

So far googling has turned up nothing that I understand. 
What am I doing wrong ?

**SOLUTION**:
I meant `former_bet = copy.deepcopy(current_bet)` instead of `former_bet = copy.deepcopy(bet)`

Comment: could you post the full trace back

Comment: The problem is that `former_bet` is not what you think it is. I don't think this line: `former_bet = copy.deepcopy(bet)` is what you want. That makes `former_bet` point to the `bet` function. Should that be `former_bet = copy.deepcopy(current_bet)`?

Comment: @Johnrednex, May be you meant `former_bet = copy.deepcopy(current_bet)` instead of`former_bet = copy.deepcopy(bet)`

Comment: @FamousJameous and _@_ kuro, thank you guys that's the solution.